# xml parsing in android from local file

Tags: android, xml

I parsed xml data successfully several times before, however its my first time doing the same in android. I tried using DOM as I usually do however an error occurs on the .parse method each time. I searched online and tried multiple times however without any success. All I need to do is get xml data from a local file to put as arguments in some functions. I implemented the code in the Main Activity's onCreate method. This is what I usully do, however this time without any success:

```
try {

                File xmlFile = new File("C:\\Users\\gg90\\Desktop\\testingxml.xml");


                DocumentBuilderFactory dbFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                DocumentBuilder dBuilder = dbFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                Document doc = dBuilder.parse(xmlFile);
                doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
```

Hope you can help me out. Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

There is no notion of a drive C: in android, so I guess your file is invalid and the parser chokes on it. Android uses a unix file system, so path look like `/data/file.xml` and so on.

To parse an xml file in the assets folder, have a look at [this code](https://github.com/pilhuhn/TurtleCar/blob/master/src/de/bsd/turtlecar/SampleView.java#L42), which opens the folder, gets the file and opens an input stream. And then calls [this method](https://github.com/pilhuhn/TurtleCar/blob/master/src/de/bsd/turtlecar/Board.java#L30).

Comment: so how is it possible to parse from a local file??

Comment: You basically need to find out where it is - unfortunately you did not say where it lives in the file system.

Comment: i tried it but the program crashes upon the line AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();     I can't believe why it is so complicated in android :S

Comment: Strange - can you add the logcat for this? The file that is read is assets/1.xml in the source project.

Comment: it says java.lang.NullPointerException :S

Comment: The context is just your activity from where you call the code. So if you are within an Activity, you can just say "AssetManager assetManager = getAssets();

Comment: ok thanks there is no error now. However im not that confident with the code till now. Can you please explain how to fetch the data from the xml tags?

Answer (score 2):

1./ in res, create new folder: raw == /res/raw
       copy file testingxml.xml and paste to folder raw

2./ parse XML from the location above by using SOM (ou SAX if you want)

```
InputStream catDoc = context.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.testingxml);

//Using factory get an instance of document builder
    DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
//parse using builder to get DOM representation of the XML file
    dom = builder.parse(catDoc, null);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try creating a folder named *raw* in the *res* folder and put the xml file there through your project in workspace. Refresh the project until it is updated in *R.java*. Then use this code:

```
InputStream file = this.getResources().openRawResource(R.raw.license_status);
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(file);
doc.getDocumentElement().normalize();
```

Answer (score 0):

so go to your project folder and find RES folder then make a new folder there named "RAW"
and place your XML file there and refresh the project until it is updated in automatically generated R.java as a class.
Now you can use R.RAW.XYZ.xml ... :)